# $X:=(X_1,X_2)$ is random variable iff $X_1$ and $X_2$ are

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

> Let $X_1, X_2: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $X(\omega):=(X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega))$. Where $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ are equipped with $\sigma$-algebras of Borel sets.  Prove that $X:=(X_1,X_2)$ is random variable iff $X_1$ and $X_2$ are.

My attempt:

"$\Rightarrow$" seemed to be essentially about projections of Borel sets to be Borel, which turned out to be false (on a positive note, I [wasn't alone](https://mathoverflow.net/a/898/36580)).

"$\Leftarrow$" I thought that Cartesian products of Borel sets are Borel, yet if the projections aren't, I'm not sure about the products anymore.

Any hints are hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let ${\cal B}$ be the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $X$ is a random variable, then $X^{-1} ( B \times \mathbb{R})= X_1^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all $B \in {\cal B}$. Hence $X_1^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for all $B \in {\cal B}$, and similarly for $X_2$. Hence $X_1, X_2$ are random variables.

Now suppose $X_1,X_2$ are random variables. Then $X^{-1} (B_1 \times B_2) = X_1^{-1}(B_1) \cap X_2^{-1} (B_2)$ which is measurable for all $B_1,B_2 \in {\cal B}$. Since sets of the form $B_1 \times B_2$ generate the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we see that $X$ is measurable.

Comment: Concerning the second part, if I understood you correctly: if $B\in \mathbb{R^2}$ is a Borel set then $B=B_1 \times B_2$ for some Borel sets $B_1, B_2$. Why is that so?

Comment: No, I just showed that the inverse of $X$ of 'rectangles' $B_1 \times B_2$ (where $B_k \in {\cal B}$) are measurable. The rectangles generate the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the collection of sets $\{ A | X^{-1}(A) \text{ is measurable} \}$ is a $\sigma$-field which contains the rectangles and hence the Borel sets.

Comment: @Did: Oops bad one. Thanks for catching that.